# How to define an array in C

Tags: c, arrays, algorithm

I'm reading the book "Cracking the Coding Interview" which contains several examples of algorithms in C. I'd like to make programs which implement these algorithms and run them as I go along.

One such algorithm is "Min and Max 1" (from the "Big O" chapter):

```
int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
for (int x : array) {
  if (x < min) min = x;
  if (x > max) max = x;
}
```

I've attempted to 'write a program around this' as follows:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int array[5] = [1, 3, 2, 5, 4];

int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;

int main(void):
{
  for (int x : array) {
    if (x < min) min = x;
    if (x > max) max = x;
  }
  printf("The minimum is %i", min)
  printf("The maximum is %i", max)
}
```

However, if I try to compile and run this I get the `error: expected identifier before numeric constant int array[5] = [1, 3, 2, 5, 4];`. How would I correctly implement this algorithm for this example input array?

Comment: it is `int array[] = {1, 3, 2, 5, 4};` (size is computed automatically from your data). And this `for (int x : array) {` is C++11 if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: Questions on how to write basic C syntax are not a good fix for SO - I recommend grabbing a good book: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you mean is the following

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

#define N   5

int main( void ) 
{
    int array[N] = { 1, 3, 2, 5, 4 };

    int min = INT_MAX;
    int max = INT_MIN;

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        if ( array[i] < min ) min = array[i];
        if ( max < array[i] ) max = array[i];
    }

    printf( "The minimum is %i\n", min );
    printf( "The maximum is %i\n", max );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
The minimum is 1
The maximum is 5
```

As for your program then it contains invalid constructions according to the C grammar.

In C++ the loop can look the same way as you showed.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

int main() 
{
    const size_t N = 5;
    int array[N] = { 1, 3, 2, 5, 4 };

    int min = std::numeric_limits<int>::max();
    int max = std::numeric_limits<int>::min();

    for ( int x : array )
    {
        if ( x < min ) min = x;
        if ( max < x ) max = x;
    }

    std::cout << "The minimum is " << min << std::endl;
    std::cout << "The maximum is " << max << std::endl; 

    return 0;
}
```

Take into account that there is no sense to declare the array like global.

As for the array definition in C then you can define it either like

```
int array[5] = { 1, 3, 2, 5, 4 };
```

(or using some named constant instead of the number 5)

or like

```
int array[] = { 1, 3, 2, 5, 4 };
```

In the last case the number of elements is equal to the number of the initializers. Or even you can use the following initialization

```
int array[] = { [0] = 1, [1] = 3, [2] = 2, [3] = 5, [4] = 4 };
```

Answer (score 1):

A few issues:

1. `int array[5] = [1, 3, 2, 5, 4];` needs to be `int array[] = {1, 3, 2, 5, 4};`
2. The short form `for` loop doesn't exist in C. (Are you using a C++11 compiler to compile C code? If so then saving your source file with a `.c` extension might be a simple way of putting it into C mode.) Use `for (size_t i = 0;` etc. instead and access the array elements by the index `i`.
3. Using `min` and `max` as variable names is to be discouraged as they frequently appear as macro definitions.

Answer (score 1):

Use C syntax to implement it in C.

- Use `{}`, not `[]`, to define the initial values of arrays.
- Use `INT_MIN` and `INT_MAX` from `limits.h` to use minimum and maximum values of `int`.
- Don't place a colon after `int main(void)`.
- `for (int x : array)` is not supported in C. Use one of the supported forms of loops.
- Semicolons are required after each statements.

Here is an implementation in C99:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<limits.h>

int array[5] = {1, 3, 2, 5, 4};

int min = INT_MAX;
int max = INT_MIN;

int main(void)
{
  for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(array) / sizeof(*array); i++) {
    int x = array[i];
    if (x < min) min = x;
    if (x > max) max = x;
  }
  printf("The minimum is %i", min);
  printf("The maximum is %i", max);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Array is initialized inside {} not []

Looks like you copied it from wrong place or you are a java Programmer.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int a[5] = {1, 3, 2, 5, 4};

int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;


int main(void):
{

  for (int x : array) {
    if (x < min) min = x;
    if (x > max) max = x;
  }
  printf("The minimum is %i", min)
  printf("The maximum is %i", max)
}
```

This will still give you error if you want i can fix it. I left it so that you can learn this by your own.